# Java-get most common element in a list

Tags: java, guava

Does Java or Guava have something that will return most common element in a list?

```
List<BigDecimal> listOfNumbers=  new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
```

[1,3,4,3,4,3,2,3,3,3,3,3]

return 3

Comment: What if there are two most occurring elements?

Comment: Are you sure you need BigDecimal here?

Comment: In the case im working on yes.....

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is fairly easy to implement yourself:

```
public static <T> T mostCommon(List<T> list) {
    Map<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (T t : list) {
        Integer val = map.get(t);
        map.put(t, val == null ? 1 : val + 1);
    }

    Entry<T, Integer> max = null;

    for (Entry<T, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
        if (max == null || e.getValue() > max.getValue())
            max = e;
    }

    return max.getKey();
}
```

---

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,3,4,3,4,3,2,3,3,3,3,3);
System.out.println(mostCommon(list));
```

```
3
```

If you want to handle cases where there's more then one most frequent element, you can scan the list once to determine how many times the most frequent element(s) occur, and then scan the list again, put those elements in a set and return that.

Comment: If the input list is empty the the return statement will cause a NullPointerException.  Even if you don't expect to ever be empty, something like this would be safer:  `return max == null ? null : max.getKey();`

Comment: This ignores the cases where a list might contain n different elements. In such case there is no most common element. if(map.size() == list.size()){return null;}

Answer (score 52):

[In statistics, this is called the "mode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)). A vanilla Java 8 solution looks like this:

```
Stream.of(1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Which yields:

```
3=8
```

[jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) is a library that supports [`mode()`](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/lambda/Collectable.html#mode--) on streams. The following program:

```
System.out.println(
    Seq.of(1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
       .mode()
);
```

Yields:

```
Optional[3]
```

For simplicity's sake, I omitted using `BigDecimal`. The solution would be the same, though.

(disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOλ)

Comment: This is the cleanest example, great job

Comment: t -> t lambda expression can be replaced with Functions.identity(). I've posted an edit proposal with appropriate change already.

Comment: @MarcinKłopotek: Thanks, yeah, why not

Answer (score 15):

Probably the simplest solution with Guava looks like

```
Multiset<BigDecimal> multiset = HashMultiset.create(listOfNumbers);
BigDecimal maxElement = null;
int maxCount = 0;
for (Multiset.Entry<BigDecimal> entry : multiset.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getCount() > maxCount) {
    maxElement = entry.getElement();
    maxCount = entry.getCount();
  }
}
```

That's a complete solution, and shorter than the other alternatives I see discussed.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a pure **Java 8** solution (note: do not use this one, see below):

```
List<Integer> theList = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3);
Integer maxOccurredElement = theList.stream()
        .reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy((o1, o2) -> Collections.frequency(theList, o1) -
                        Collections.frequency(theList, o2))).orElse(null);
System.out.println(maxOccurredElement);
```

Another solution, by collecting the elements to a map by their frequency, then finding the entry with max value and returning its key (basically the same solution on [arshajii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19031350/1005102), written using Java 8):

```
Integer maxVal = theList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream().max((o1, o2) -> o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(null);
```

**Update:** If the most frequent elements are more than one, and you want to get all of them in a collection, I propose two methods:

**Method A:** After collecting the original collection to a map with keys as elements and values as their number of occurrences, getting the entry with the maximum value and filtering the map entries with value equal to this max value (if) we found. Something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Long> elementCountMap = theList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
List<Integer> result = elementCountMap.values().stream()
        .max(Long::compareTo).map(maxValue -> elementCountMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> maxValue.equals(entry.getValue())).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

**Method B:** After collecting the original collection to a map with keys as elements and values as their number of occurrences, transforming this map into a new map with keys as number of occurences, values as a list of elements with this number of occurences. And then finding the max element of this map with a custom comparator which compares the keys, and getting the value of this entry. Like this:

```
List<Integer> result = theList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
    .entrySet().stream().max((o1, o2) -> o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey())).map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Comment: This algorithm has `O(N^2)` complexity for something that's feasible in `O(N)`...

Comment: @LukasEder true, calling `Collections.frequency()` over and over is not feasible, I did not consider complexity while writing the answer. Edited and added another solution though, which has `O(N)` complexity.

Comment: Very nice alternative solution!

Comment: I like the second solution.. but does it handle cases when more than one element has the same frequency? I can't tell as I'm new to Java. if not, can it be modified to just return one of several element that have the same number of occurances?

Comment: @Kai Unfortunately not, it cannot handle the case with more than one elements with same frequency. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334404/how-to-force-max-to-return-all-maximum-values-in-a-java-stream     
But please see my update on the answer, I added solutions to this case as well.

Comment: @UtkuÖzdemir: very nice. Thank you! one question: Method B can return elements that have the same frequency. Why do you still need the last part => orElse(empty list)? is it to guard against cases were the original list is empty or contains one element only?

Comment: @Kai method `max(comparator)` of a stream (or an optional) returns a `java.util.Optional`, because if no elements pass from the stream, a "maximum element" simply does not exist. So it's only for the case when the input collection is empty. And I prefer to fall to an empty list when there's no max element since it's expected from the operation to return a list, and returning an empty collection is always a bad idea, according to the best practices.

Answer (score 9):

Guava provides a [method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#copyHighestCountFirst%28com.google.common.collect.Multiset%29) that will help, though it's less efficient than Louis's solution.

```
BigDecimal mostCommon = 
    Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(listOfNumbers))
        .iterator().next();
```

Answer (score 3):

The classic way to do this is to sort the list and then work through them one by one:

```
public static BigInteger findMostCommon(List<BigInteger> list) {
    Collections.sort(list);
    BigInteger mostCommon = null;
    BigInteger last = null;
    int mostCount = 0;
    int lastCount = 0;
    for (BigInteger x : list) {
        if (x.equals(last)) {
            lastCount++;
        } else if (lastCount > mostCount) {
            mostCount = lastCount;
            mostCommon = last;
        }
        last = x;
    }
    return mostCommon;
}
```

This is a bit more space efficient than using a hash to tally counts since it sorts the array in place.  You could toss this into a generics class and replace BigInteger with T, or just use Object in place of BigInteger.

Comment: This algorithm has `O(N * log N)` complexity for something that can be done in `O(N)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension of Louis' answer that support the case where there is multiple elements with same max occurrence count:

```
private <T> List<T> getMostFrequentElements(List<T> list) {
    Multiset<T> multiset = HashMultiset.create(list);

    List<T> mostFrequents = new ArrayList<>();
    int maxCount = 0;

    for (Multiset.Entry<T> entry : multiset.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getCount() > maxCount) {
            maxCount = entry.getCount();
            mostFrequents.clear();
            mostFrequents.add(entry.getElement());
        } else if (entry.getCount() == maxCount) {
            mostFrequents.add(entry.getElement());
        }
    }

    return mostFrequents;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**We can do in only one iteration with ease:**

```
public static Integer mostFrequent(List<Integer> list) {

    if (list == null || list.isEmpty())
        return null;

    Map<Integer, Integer> counterMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Integer maxValue = 0;
    Integer mostFrequentValue = null;

    for(Integer valueAsKey : list) {
        Integer counter = counterMap.get(valueAsKey);
        counterMap.put(valueAsKey, counter == null ? 1 : counter + 1);
        counter = counterMap.get(valueAsKey);
        if (counter > maxValue) {
            maxValue = counter;
            mostFrequentValue = valueAsKey;
        }
    }
    return mostFrequentValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find most frequent item in collection:

```
private <V> V findMostFrequentItem(final Collection<V> items)
{
  return items.stream()
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Functions.identity(), Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream()
      .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
      .map(Entry::getKey)
      .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use Google Guava, you can use its `MultiSet` classes:

```
MultiSet<BigNumber> numbers = HashMultiSet.create();
numberSet.addAll(list);
Set<MultiSet.Entry<BigNumber>> pairs = numbers.emtrySet();
Set<MultiSet.Entry<BigNumber>> copies = new HashSet<MultiSet.Entry<BigNumber>>(pairs);
```

Now, sort `copies` by its values descending.