# Find the most common String in ArrayList()

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

Is there a way to find the most common `String` in an `ArrayList`?

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("test");
list.add("test");
list.add("hello");
list.add("test");
```

Should find the word "test" from this list `["test","test","hello","test"]`

Comment: Yes there is a way. But no direct one. You've to write some code.

Comment: Yes, you have to use Map for instance HashMap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java-get most common element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031213/java-get-most-common-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use the `frequency` method of the `Collections` class:

```
public static int frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o)
```

> Returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to
>   the specified object. More formally, returns the number of elements e
>   in the collection such that (o == null ? e == null : o.equals(e)).

If you need to *count* the occurrences for all elements, use a Map and loop cleverly :)
Or put your list in a Set and loop on each element of the set with the `frequency` method above. HTH

**EDIT / Java 8**: If you fancy a more functional, Java 8 one-liner solution with lambdas, try:

```
Map<String, Long> occurrences = 
  list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Instead of `w->w` use `Function.identity()`

Comment: this doesn't return the frequency of each word within each String. It returns the most reoccurring String.. How can i adapt this to return the most frequent words that appear in an ArrayList of Strings

Comment: @Cemo I personally find `w -> w` less verbose in a language where more terseness wouldn't hurt much. Any strong argument in favor of `Function.identity()`?

Answer (score 11):

[In statistics, this is called the "mode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)). A vanilla Java 8 solution looks like this:

```
Stream.of("test","test","hello","test")
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()))
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Which yields:

```
test=3
```

[jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) is a library that supports [`mode()`](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/lambda/Collectable.html#mode--) on streams. The following program:

```
System.out.println(
    Seq.of("test","test","hello","test")
       .mode()
);
```

Yields:

```
Optional[test]
```

(disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOλ)

Answer (score 9):

As per question, Specifically just to get word, not the number of times (i.e. value of key).

```
String mostRepeatedWord 
    = list.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()))
          .entrySet()
          .stream()
          .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
          .get()
          .getKey();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make a `HashMap<String,Integer>`. If the String already appears in the map, increment its *key* by one, otherwise, add it to the map.

For example:

```
put("someValue", 1);
```

Then, assume it's "someValue" again, you can do:

```
put("someValue", get("someValue") + 1);
```

Since the *key* of "someValue" is 1, now when you put it, the key will be 2.

After that you can easily go through the map and extract the *key* that has the highest *value*.

<sup>I didn't write a full solution, try to construct one, if you have problems post it in another question. Best practice is to learn by yourself.</sup>

Comment: Hint: Use `yourMap.compute("someValue", (k, counter) -> counter == null ? 0 : counter + 1)` for the insertion of the map!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do it is using maps containing counts.

```
Map<String, Integer> stringsCount = new HashMap<>();
```

And iterate over your array filling this map:

```
for(String s: list)
{
  Integer c = stringsCount.get(s);
  if(c == null) c = new Integer(0);
  c++;
  stringsCount.put(s,c);
}
```

Finally, you can get the most repeated element iterating over the map:

```
Map.Entry<String,Integer> mostRepeated = null;
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: stringsCount.entrySet())
{
    if(mostRepeated == null || mostRepeated.getValue()<e.getValue())
        mostRepeated = e;
}
```

And show the most common string:

```
if(mostRepeated != null)
        System.out.println("Most common string: " + mostRepeated.getKey());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `HashMap<String,Integer>`. Looping through the array, you can check for each `String` if it is not already a Key of your `HashMap`, add it and set the value to 1, if it is, increase its value by 1.

Then you have a `HashMap` with all unique `String`s and an associated number stating their amount in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody need to find most popular from usual String[] array (using Lists):

```
public String findPopular (String[] array) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    Map<String, Integer> stringsCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(String string: list)
    {
        if (string.length() > 0) {
            string = string.toLowerCase();
            Integer count = stringsCount.get(string);
            if(count == null) count = new Integer(0);
            count++;
            stringsCount.put(string,count);
        }
    }
    Map.Entry<String,Integer> mostRepeated = null;
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: stringsCount.entrySet())
    {
        if(mostRepeated == null || mostRepeated.getValue()<e.getValue())
            mostRepeated = e;
    }
    try {
        return mostRepeated.getKey();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot find most popular value at the List. Maybe all strings are empty");
        return "";
    }

}
```

- case non-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

i know this takes more time to implement but you can use heap data structure by storing in the nodes the count and the string information

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava's Multiset:

```
ArrayList<String> names = ...

// count names 
HashMultiset<String> namesCounts = HashMultiset.create(names);
Set<Multiset.Entry<String>> namesAndCounts = namesCounts.entrySet();

// find one most common
Multiset.Entry<String> maxNameByCount = Collections.max(namesAndCounts, Comparator.comparing(Multiset.Entry::getCount));

// pick all with the same number of occurrences
List<String> mostCommonNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (Multiset.Entry<String> nameAndCount : namesAndCounts) {
    if (nameAndCount.getCount() == maxNameByCount.getCount()) {
        mostCommonNames.add(nameAndCount.getElement());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
```

public class StringChecker {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList<String> string;
string = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Mah", "Bob", "mah", "bat", "MAh", "BOb"));
Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String st : string) {
    String input = st.toUpperCase();
    if (wordMap.get(input) != null) {
        Integer count = wordMap.get(input) + 1;
        wordMap.put(input, count);
    } else {
        wordMap.put(input, 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(wordMap);
Object maxEntry = Collections.max(wordMap.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
System.out.println("maxEntry = " + maxEntry);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

With this method, if there is more than one most common elements in your ArrayList, you get back all of them by adding them to a new ArrayList.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 List <String> words = new ArrayList<>() ; 

words.add("cat") ; 
words.add("dog") ; 
words.add("egg") ; 
words.add("chair") ; 
words.add("chair") ; 
words.add("chair") ; 
words.add("dog") ; 
words.add("dog") ;  

Map<String,Integer> count = new HashMap<>() ; 

    for (String word : words) {  /* Counts the quantity of each 
                                      element */
        if (! count.containsKey(word)) {             
            count.put(word, 1 ) ; 
        }

        else {
            int value = count.get(word) ; 
            value++ ; 

            count.put(word, value) ;
        }       
    }

    List <String> mostCommons = new ArrayList<>() ; /* Max elements  */

    for ( Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : count.entrySet() ) {

        if (e.getValue() == Collections.max(count.values() )){
                            /* The max value of count  */

            mostCommons.add(e.getKey()) ;
        }   
    }

    System.out.println(mostCommons);

 }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of answers suggesting HashMaps. I really don't like them, because you have to iterate through them once again anyway. Rather, I would sort the List

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

and then loop through it. Something similar to

```
String prev = null, mostCommon=null;
int num = 0, max = 0;
for (String str:list) {
  if (str.equals(prev)) {
    num++;
  } else {
    if (num>max) {
      max = num;
      mostCommon = str;
    }
    num = 1;
    prev = str;
  }
}
```

should do it.

Comment: *"I really don't like them"* ... Iterating through a set of values twice is still of `O(N)` complexity. Your algorithm uses sorting, which is `O(N log N)` complexity, which is certainly worse.

Comment: I agree with Bex. Sort is actually not a bad idea in my opinion. It's easy to implement and has a O(nlogn) time complexity and O(1) space. While use hashmap and priorityqueue has O(nlogn) time complexity and O(n) space. Since insert into a pq is O(logn), iterate the entries of Hashmap and insert them into pq is O(nlogn) in worst cases. Correct me if I'm wrong. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html