# How to implement a thread-safe Collector?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

I want to have something similar to `Collectors.maxBy()`, a collector that gets the top elements in a collection (`maxBy` only gets one).

I have a stream of `Possibility` objects that could be scored with an `Integer score(Possibility)` method.

First I tried:

```
List<Possibity> possibilities = getPossibilityStream()
    .parallel()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

if(!possibilities.isEmpty()) {
    int bestScore = possibilities.stream()
        .mapToInt(p -> score(p))
        .max()
        .getAsInt();
    possibilities = possibilities.stream()
        .filter(p -> score(p)==bestScore)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But doing that, I scan the collection three times. Once to build it, a second time to get the top score, and a third time to filter it and that is not optimal. Moreover the number of possibiities could be huge (>10<sup>12</sup>).

The best way should be to directly get the top possibilities in the first collect but there seems to be no built in collector to do such a thing.

So I implemented my own `Collector`:

```
public class BestCollector<E> implements Collector<E, List<E>, List<E>> {

    private final Comparator<E> comparator;

    private final Class<? extends List> listImpl ;

    public BestCollector(Comparator<E> comparator, Class<? extends List> listImpl) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
        this.listImpl = listImpl;
    }

    public BestCollector(Comparator<E> comparator) {
        this.comparator= comparator;
        listImpl = ArrayList.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<List<E>> supplier() {
        return () -> {
            try {
                return listImpl.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<E>, E> accumulator() {
        return (list, e) -> {
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                list.add(e);
            } else {
                final int comparison = comparator.compare(list.get(0), e);
                if (comparison == 0) {
                    list.add(e);
                } else if (comparison < 0) {
                    list.clear();
                    list.add(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<E>> combiner() {
        return (l1, l2) -> {
            final int comparison = comparator.compare(l1.get(0), l2.get(0));
            if (comparison == 0) {
                l1.addAll(l2);
                return l1;
            } else if (comparison < 0) {
                return l2;
            } else {
                return l1;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<E>, List<E>> finisher() {
        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH, Characteristics.CONCURRENT, Characteristics.UNORDERED);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
List<Possibity> possibilities = getPossibilityStream()
    .parallel()
    .collect(new BestCollector<Possibility>((p1, p2) -> score(p1).compareTo(score(p2)));
```

And that does the job in a sequential mode (without the `.parallel()`) but in parallel mode there are some exceptions occasionally in two spots:

- A `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0` in the line:

  ```
  final int comparison = comparator.compare(list.get(0), e);
  ```

of the `accumulator()` method

I understand it happens when a `list.clear()` is called between `list.isEmpty()` and `list.get(0)`.

- A `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the score(Possibility) method because the possibility is `null`. Again the same line is involved:

  ```
  final int comparison = comparator.compare(list.get(0), e);
  ```

I don't understand how `list.get(0)` could return `null`...

In parallel mode, sometimes `list.get(0)` raises a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and sometimes return `null`.

I understand that my code is not thread safe so I tried several solutions:

- Add `synchronized` in all methods of BestCollector: `public synchronized …`
- Use a thread-safe collection instead of `ArrayList`: `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`
- Add `synchronized` and use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` at the same time
- Remove `Characteristics.CONCURRENT` out of the `Set<Characteristics>` of the `characteristics()` method

  ```
  @Override
  public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
      return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH, Characteristics.UNORDERED);
  }
  ```

But I don't know if the `Characteristics.CONCURRENT` is here to indicate that my code is thread safe or that my code will be used in a concurrency processing.

But none of these solutions actually solve the problem.

---

In fact when I remove CONCURRENT out of the characteristics there is, sometimes, a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` but in the line:

```
final int comparison = comparator.compare(l1.get(0), l2.get(0));
```

of the `combiner()` method.

However, the exceptions raised by the `accumulator()` method seem to not occur anymore.

---

@Holger's answer is right.

The complete solution is to change both `combiner()` and `characteristics()` methods:

```
@Override
public BinaryOperator<List<E>> combiner() {
    return (l1, l2) -> {
        if (l1.isEmpty()) {
            return l2;
        } else if (l2.isEmpty()) {
            return l1;
        } else {
            final int comparison = comparator.compare(l1.get(0), l2.get(0));
            if (comparison == 0) {
                l1.addAll(l2);
                return l1;
            } else if (comparison < 0) {
                return l2;
            } else {
                return l1;
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
    return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH, Characteristics.UNORDERED);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your Collector implementation (which is basically the same implementation of the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334404/how-to-force-max-to-return-all-maximum-values-in-a-java-stream/29334774)

Comment: Interestingly, removing the `CONCURRENT` characteristic makes it working for me, so I guess you'd have to look into this direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code has only one significant error: if your collector is not thread safe, it shouldn’t report `Characteristics.CONCURRENT` as that is exactly claiming that it was thread safe.

The important point you have to understand is that for non-`CONCURRENT` collectors, the framework will perform the necessary steps to use it in a thread-safe but still efficient manner:

- for each worker thread, a new container will be acquired via the `supplier()`
- each worker will use the `accumulator()` function together with its own local container
- the `combiner()` will be used once two worker thread have finished their work
- the `finisher()` will be used when *all* worker threads have finished their work and all containers have been combined

So all you have to do is to ensure that your supplier truly returns a new instance on each invocation and that all functions are non-interfering and side-effect free (regarding anything else but the container they receive as arguments) and, of course, not report `Characteristics.CONCURRENT` when your collector isn’t a concurrent collector.

You don’t need the `synchronized` keyword nor concurrent collections here.

---

By the way, a `Comparator` of the form `(p1, p2) -> score(p1).compareTo(score(p2))` can be implemented using `Comparator.comparing(p -> score(p))` or if the score value is an `int`: `Comparator.comparingInt(p -> score(p))`.

---

Finally, your combiner function does not check whether one of the lists is empty. This perfectly explains an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` within the `combiner` while the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` within the `accumulator` is the result of your collector reporting `Characteristics.CONCURRENT`…

---

It’s also important to understand that adding a `synchronized` keyword to an `accumulator()` or `combiner()` method does not guard the function constructed via lambda expression. It will guard the method which *constructs* the function instance, but not the function’s code itself. In contrast to an inner class, there is no way the add a `synchronized` keyword to the actual function’s implementation method.

Comment: Yes I saw that the `synchronized` don't behave like it use to... Also I try to add a synchronized block : `synchronized(list) {...` in the `accumulator()` method, keep the `CONCURRENT` in the characteristics set and don't check for `isEmpty()` in the `combiner()` method and it's working too but your solution is faster in terms of execution time