# How to choose one of the largest elements in a collection

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of tuples, and I want to find the tuples with the largest `x` value. In the case where there are multiple largest `x` values, I want to choose one at random. I can't figure out how to implement this random selection functionality. Below is the code I have so far:

```
public void testSelectRandomFromLargestVals() {
    List<Tuple<Integer, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Tuple<>(5, "five-1"));
    list.add(new Tuple<>(2, "two"));
    list.add(new Tuple<>(3, "three"));
    list.add(new Tuple<>(5, "five-2"));
    list.add(new Tuple<>(5, "five-3"));

    Optional<Tuple<Integer, String>> largestTuple = list.stream().max((t1, t2) -> Integer.compare(t1.x, t2.x));
    System.out.println("Largest tuple is: " + largestTuple.get().x + " value is: " + largestTuple.get().y);
}

public class Tuple<X, Y> {
    public final X x;
    public final Y y;
    public Tuple(X x, Y y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Tuple<?, ?> tuple = (Tuple<?, ?>) o;
        if (!x.equals(tuple.x)) return false;
        return y.equals(tuple.y);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = x.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + y.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334404/how-to-force-max-to-return-all-maximum-values-in-a-java-stream/29339106

Comment: Just to be clear, you do really mean "at random", as opposed to "arbitrarily"?

Comment: Your equals method would be more safely implements using `Objects.equal(x, tuple.x)` instead of `x.equals(tuple.x)` (similarly `Objects.hash(x, y)` in `hashCode`).

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, random. The equals and hashcode methods were auto-generated by IntelliJ

Comment: Then IntelliJ should add null checks in the constructor :) Notwithstanding that, `return x.equals(tuple.x) && y.equals(tuple.y)` is a much nicer way to express the `equals` condition.

Comment: @AndyTurner Regarding IntelliJ, you can tell it to add null checks on equals and hashCode or not

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that [Misha's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998302/1441122) one-pass random selector (nice work, +1) can be combined with my one-pass max-value collector from this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339106/1441122) into a single collector. This allows a random element from the set of maximal ones to be selected in a single pass.

Here's the merged collector:

```
static <T> Collector<T, ?, Optional<T>> rndMax(Comparator<? super T> cmp) {
    class RndMax {
        T val;
        int cnt;

        void add(T t) {
            int c;
            if (cnt == 0 || (c = cmp.compare(t, val)) > 0) {
                cnt = 1;
                val = t;
            } else if (c == 0) {
                cnt++;
                if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(cnt) == 0) {
                    val = t;
                }
            }
        }

        RndMax merge(RndMax other) {
            if (cnt == 0) {
                return other;
            }

            if (other.cnt == 0) {
                return this;
            }

            int c = cmp.compare(val, other.val);
            if (c < 0) {
                return other;
            } else if (c > 0) {
                return this;
            } else {
                cnt += other.cnt;
                if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(cnt) < other.cnt) {
                    val = other.val;
                }
                return this;
            }
        }

        Optional<T> finish() {
            return cnt == 0 ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(val);
        }
    }

    return Collector.of(RndMax::new, RndMax::add, RndMax::merge, RndMax::finish);
}
```

You'd invoke it like this:

```
List<Tuple<Integer,String>> list = ... ;
Optional<Tuple<Integer,String>> max =
    list.stream().collect(rndMax(Comparator.comparingInt(t -> t.x)));
```

Comment: Another approach would be to make a `groupMax` collector that accepts a downstream collector.  Then it can be composed with `random()` to solve this problem or `toList()` to solve the problem in the other question you linked.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of that but this one seemed complicated enough to start with. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer is to shuffle first:

```
List<Tuple<Integer, String>> copy = new ArrayList<>(list);
Collections.shuffle(copy);
Tuple<Integer, String> largestTuple = Collections.max(copy, Comparator.comparingInt(t -> t.x)); // credit @Holger
```

The element returned by `max()` is influenced by encounter order, so shuffling effectively makes it random.

If the list is not too big (not thousands of elements), the shuffle will be pretty fast.

I made a copy of the list so as to not affect the order of the original list. If that isn't important, just shuffle as use the original list.

Comment: Hmm ok, what if instead of a List<Tuple<Integer,String>> I have a Set<Tuple<Integer, String>> ?

Comment: @jcm you can only shuffle a `List`, but you can pass any Collection type to the constructor of `ArrayList` to make a copy, so this code will work as-is with a `Set` too.

Comment: the Set can be quite large so I was hoping to not have to make a copy of it. My ideal solution would be to implement the random selection as part of the stream processing code.

Comment: @jcm how large exactly?

Comment: Potentially thousands of elements

Comment: @jcm I just did a quick benchmark on my average laptop: To copy and shuffle a random collection of integers of size 10K takes about 0.5ms, size 1K about 0.05ms and size 100K about 6ms. Unless you're doing this continuously, I doubt you'll feel it. A user definitely won't notice it.

Comment: If you’re operating on a shuffled list, there is no need for using the stream API at all. Just use [`Collections.max(copy, comparingInt(t->t.x))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-)

Comment: @jcm I wrote a simple test harness, allowed warm up, used random data, ran several times.

Answer (score 5):

For most practical purposes, @Bohemian's shuffle-based solution is the best, but since you expressed an interest in an approach that's constant in memory, you can do it with a custom `Collector` that chooses a random element:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Optional<T>> random() {
    class Rnd {

        T val;
        int cnt;

        void add(T t) {
            cnt++;
            if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(cnt) == 0) {
                val = t;
            }
        }

        Rnd merge(Rnd other) {
            cnt += other.cnt;
            if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(cnt) < other.cnt) {
                val = other.val;
            }
            return this;
        }

        Optional<T> finish() {
            return cnt == 0 ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(val);
        }

    }

    return Collector.of(Rnd::new, Rnd::add, Rnd::merge, Rnd::finish);
}
```

With that, you can make one pass to find the largest `x` and another to pick a random matching tuple:

```
int largestX = list.stream().mapToInt(t -> t.x).max()
        .getAsInt();  // or throw if list is empty

Tuple<Integer, String> randomLargestTuple = list.stream()
        .filter(t -> largestX == t.x)
        .collect(random())
        .get();
```

Comment: Do you mean "you can do it with a custom `Collector` that chooses a random element"?

Comment: Thank you for catching that.  fixed.

Comment: Nice work! +1. See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36002464/1441122) for a one-pass variation.

Answer (score 2):

Might not be an optimal solution

```
    final Optional<Tuple<Integer, String>> largestTuple = list.stream().max((t1, t2) -> Integer.compare(t1.x, t2.x));
    final List<Tuple<Integer, String>> allMaxElements = list.stream().filter(z -> z.x == largestTuple.get().x).collect(Collectors.toList());
    final Tuple<Integer, String> randomMaxTuple = allMaxElements.get(new SecureRandom().nextInt(allMaxElements.size()));
    System.out.println("Largest tuple is: " + randomMaxTuple.x + " value is: " + randomMaxTuple.y);
```

On the equals and hashCode methods you can utilize guava

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return com.google.common.base.Objects.hashCode(x, y);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object object)
{
    if (object instanceof Tuple) {
        final Tuple<?, ?> that = (Tuple<?, ?>) object;
        return com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(this.x, that.x) && com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(this.y, that.y);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: fyi java 8 has made those guava methods obsolete: `java.util.Objects.hash()` and `java.util.Objects.equals()` do exactly the same thing.

Comment: good to know, I tried googling and couldn't find a link that would describe this in detail, can you share any?

Comment: Always try [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) first. [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) • [`Objects.hash`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-)

Answer (score 1):

You could collect your tuples to a `TreeMap`, with the key being each possible `x` value from the tuples and the values being a list of all tuples that have that `x` value:

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<Tuple<Integer, String>>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        t -> t.x, 
        TreeMap::new, 
        Collectors.toList()));
```

Then, you could grab the entry with the maximum key by using the `TreeMap.lastEntry()` method:

```
List<Tuple<Integer, String>> largestTuples = map.lastEntry().getValue();
```

Then, simply pick one element randomly from the `largestTuples` list.

Answer (score 0):

@Misha's custom `Collector` can also be implemented with an anonymous type, instead of a local class:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Optional<T>> random() {
  return Collector.of(
    () -> new Object() {
      T val;
      int cnt;
    },
    (this_, t) -> {
      this_.cnt++;
      if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(this_.cnt) == 0) {
        this_.val = t;
      }
    },
    (this_, other) -> {
      this_.cnt += other.cnt;
      if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(this_.cnt) < other.cnt) {
        this_.val = other.val;
      }
      return this_;
    },
    this_ -> this_.cnt == 0
      ? Optional.empty()
      : Optional.of(this_.val)
  );
}
```