# Shuffle Stream using sort - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this commands:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(e -> ...)
    .sorted(comparatorShuffle())
    .findAny()
    .orElse(null);
```

This is `comparatorShuffle()`:

```
public static <E> Comparator<E> comparatorShuffle(){

    return new Comparator<>(){
        private final List<Integer> temp = List.of(-1, 1);
        private final Random random = new Random();
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("ComparatorMethodParameterNotUsed")
        public int compare(E o1, E o2){
            return temp.get(random.nextInt(temp.size()));
        }
    };

}
```

Sometimes I get an exception: `IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`

I understand why I get this, it's because the sort(it's random) don't respect the rule: `if A > B && B > C then A > C`

There is a way to suppress/ignore this error? Or another way to shuffle the stream without using `collect`?

Comment: Your comparator is not a proper comparator. It violates the comparator protocol. This is also not a sensible way to randomly sample or shuffle in the first place.

Comment: @kaya3 "It violates the comparator protocol" OP knows this ("I understand why I get this").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is a way to suppress/ignore this error?

No.

You're not really shuffling here, you're ostensibly just trying to pick a random element from the stream.

To do this, you can pair up the elements with a random number and pick the min/max:

```
...
.map(a -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(Math.random(), a))
.min(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
.map(Map.Entry::getValue)
.orElse(null)
```

---

Alternatively, you can write a custom collector which randomly picks between two things when merging:

```
.collect(
    Collector.of(
        // Use Optional.empty() as the identity element, if the stream is empty.
        Optional::empty,
        // Optionalize the element, taking it randomly or if we have the identity element.
        (a, b) -> a.isEmpty() || Math.random() > 0.5 ? Optional.of(b) : a,
        // Merge.
        (a, b) -> Math.random() > 0.5 ? b : a,
        // Unwrap the value.
        r -> r.orElse(null)))
```

The big problem with this alternative is it doesn't pick uniformly from the stream (you're not equally likely to get any one of the elements from the stream), whereas you are with the first way.

Comment: `You're not really shuffling here, you're ostensibly just trying to pick a random element from the stream.` true

Comment: I have a warning at `Optional::of` - `Static method referenced through receiver`

Comment: @kaya3 yep, I was concerned about that. And since the "alternative" ended up neater, I swapped them round.

Comment: That's weird, your edit was 4 minutes before my comment, but SO still showed me the old version when I commented.

Comment: `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(k, v)` ... or just `Map.entry(k, v)`.

Comment: Your solution with `Map.Entry` is ok for me. Thank you. But also I will gonna look for something which can be implemented in a method and reuse.

Comment: @KunLun you can put the `Map.Entry` way in a method.

Comment: You can actually solve the non-uniformity problem using [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). The simplest version would be: where your code uses `Math.random() > 0.5`, instead make the threshold be `1 / [num items seen so far]`.

Comment: If you want a correct `Collector` picking one random element, consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998302/2711488). If you want to sort all elements in an order that’s actually shuffling, see [Shuffle/Random comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29241746/2711488).