# Java Streams: Organize a collection into a map and select smallest key

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm pretty sure this is not possible in one line, but I just wanted to check:

```
List<WidgetItem> selectedItems = null;
Map<Integer, List<WidgetItem>> itemsByStockAvailable = WidgetItems.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(WidgetItem::getAvailableStock));
selectedItems = itemsByStockAvailable.get(
     itemsByStockAvailable.keySet().stream().sorted().findFirst().get());
```

Basically I'm collecting all widget items into a map where the key is the availableStock quantity and the value is a list of all widgets that have that quantity (since multiple widgets might have the same value). Once I have that map, I would want to select the map's value that corresponds to the smallest key. The intermediate step of creating a Map isn't necessary, it's just the only way I could think of to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears what you want is to keep all the widget items that were grouped with the lowest available stock. In that case, you can collect the grouped data into a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to ensure the ordering based on increasing values of the stock and retrieve the first entry with [`firstEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#firstEntry--)

```
List<WidgetItem> selectedItems = 
    widgetItems.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                  WidgetItem::getAvailableStock,
                  TreeMap::new,
                  Collectors.toList()
               ))
               .firstEntry()
               .getValue();
```

The advantage is that it is done is one-pass over the initial list.

Comment: Ah- TreeMap. I forgot about that Class as it's been a while since I had to use it. Thanks!

Comment: If you prefer to cram everything into one stream, you could also do `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(...),  x -> x.firstEntry().getValue())`

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you want to get all the input elements which are minimal according to the custom comparator `Comparator.comparingInt(WidgetItem::getAvailableStock)`. In general this problem could be solved without necessity to store everything into the intermediate map creating unnecessary garbage. Also it could be solved in single pass. Some interesting solutions already present in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29334404/4856258) question. For example, you may use the collector implemented by [Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339106/4856258):

```
List<WidgetItem> selectedItems = widgetItems.stream()
           .collect(maxList(
               Comparator.comparingInt(WidgetItem::getAvailableStock).reversed()));
```

Such collectors are readily available in my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library. The best suitable in your case is [`MoreCollectors.minAll(Comparator)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#minAll-java.util.Comparator-):

```
List<WidgetItem> selectedItems = widgetItems.stream()
           .collect(MoreCollectors.minAll(
               Comparator.comparingInt(WidgetItem::getAvailableStock)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the smallest key in a first pass and then get all the items having that smallest key:

```
widgetItems.stream()
           .map(WidgetItem::getAvailableStock)
           .min(Comparator.naturalOrder())
           .map(min -> 
               widgetItems.stream()
                          .filter(item -> item.getAvailableStock().equals(min))
                          .collect(toList()))
           .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid creating the intermediate map, you can first determine the smallest stock value, filter by that value and collect to list.

```
int minStock = widgetItems.stream()
    .mapToInt(WidgetItem::getAvailableStock)
    .min()
    .getAsInt();  // or throw if list is empty

List<WidgetItem> selectItems = widgetItems.stream()
    .filter(w -> minStock == w.getAvailableStock())
    .collect(toList());
```

Also, do not use `sorted().findFirst()` to find the min value of a stream.  Use `min` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would collect the data into a NavigableMap, which involves only a small change to your original code:

```
List<WidgetItem> selectedItems = null;
NavigableMap<Integer, List<WidgetItem>> itemsByStockAvailable =
    WidgetItems.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(WidgetItem::getAvailableStock,
            TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
selectedItems = itemsByStockAvailable.firstEntry().getValue();
```