# List stream, get items with lowest price

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List<Hotel>`, each `Hotel` have a `BigDecimal minSellingPrice`, I want to get the `Hotel` with the minimum selling price.

I was able to achieve this via this code

```
hotels.stream().min((h1, h2) -> h1.getMinSellingPrice().compareTo(h2.getMinSellingPrice())).get()
```

But what if 3 hotels in the list have the minimum selling price in common, so the list have 50 hotels, lowest `minSellingPrice` is 100, 3 hotels out of 50 have a `minSellingPrice` of 100.

How can I get a list of those 3 hotels so I can operate on them? The only thing I thought of is getting the minimum price via `map` and `min` then querying the list for the items that have this lowest price, but that doesn't sound too nice.

Comment: Filter `hotels.stream()` for the value you get above. Technically, you only need to traverse once since no backtracking is required here. Maybe create a custom filter that adds to another list if multiple occurrences are found.

Comment: See [“How to force max() to return ALL maximum values in a Java Stream?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29334404/2711488), the logic for minimum is the same…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the form of [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) that allows you to specify the type of `Map` to use, and specify a `SortedMap` or `NavigableMap` implementation. Then you can easily retrieve the collection of minimal elements from the result.

```
NavigableMap<BigDecimal, List<Hotel>> hotelByPrice = hotels.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Hotel::getMinSellingPrice, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
List<Hotel> cheapest = hotelByPrice.firstEntry().getValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try below to get the min hotel

```
Hotel min = hotels.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getSellingPrice)).orElse(null);
```

in order to get more than one hotels, you need to use groupingBy

```
Map<BigDecimal, List<Hotel>> groupedHoted = hotels.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Hotel::getSellingPrice, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

**Update**

edited as per comments

```
groupedHoted = new TreeMap<>(hotels.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Hotel::getSellingPrice)));
```

using reduce (less recommended)

```
    Map<BigDecimal, List<Hotel>> sorted = hotels.stream().reduce(new TreeMap<BigDecimal, List<Hotel>>(), (map, hotel) -> {
        if (map.get(hotel.getSellingPrice()) == null) {
            map.put(hotel.getSellingPrice(), new ArrayList<>());
        }
        map.get(hotel.getSellingPrice()).add(hotel);
        return map;
    }, (map1, map2) -> {
        map1.putAll(map2);
        return map1;
    });
```

output

```
{10=[Hotel [sellingPrice=10], Hotel [sellingPrice=10]], 20=[Hotel [sellingPrice=20], Hotel [sellingPrice=20]], 30=[Hotel [sellingPrice=30]]}
```

Comment: @erickson I didn't copy you, I have answered similar questions already in SO, I understood the question wrongly then I corrected my answer

Comment: @erickson edited my answer, the map it sorted, user can iterate and get the number of hotels they want

Comment: Thanks. By the way there is no difference between your 2nd code block and the 3rd. It was tough for me to accept an answer so I accepted the one that posted earlier. Appreciated however :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the list of Hotels:

```
Comparator<Hotel> comp = new Comparator<Hotel>() {
            public int compare(Hotel o1, Hotel o2) {
                return o1.getMinSellingPrice() - o2.getMinSellingPrice();
            }
        };

hotels = hotels.stream().sorted(comp).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This uses a comparator, [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Or to return the minimum selling price in the list:

```
hotels.stream().map(i -> i.getMinSellingPrice()).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get());
```

This simply maps the list of hotels to a list of their minSellingPrice's, then takes the smallest value.

Comment: Thanks, I might need to sort some results soon.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility.

```
List<Hotel> minHotels = hotels.stream()
    .filter(h -> h.minSellingPrice == hotels.stream()
        .map(Hotel::getMinSellingPrice).sorted().findFirst().orElse(null))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```