# Using Java8 Stream to find the highest values from map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wrote following method to find the keys mapped to the highest values and trying to convert to java `Stream`s. Can you please help?

```
private List<Integer> testStreamMap(Map<Integer, Long> mapGroup) 
{
    List<Integer> listMax = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Long frequency = 0L;
    for (Integer key : mapGroup.keySet()) {
        Long occurrence = mapGroup.get(key);
        if (occurrence > frequency) {
            listMax.clear();
            listMax.add(key);
            frequency = occurrence;
        } else if (occurrence == frequency) {
            listMax.add(key);
        }
    }
    return listMax;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, the same parameter that you called `occurance`( which is misspelled btw) is called in the second implementation `tempValue`. And the parameter that you named `frequencey` (which is also misspelled) in the first implementation is called `occurrence` in the second. Start by being consistent with your names and that might help you solve your confusion.

Comment: "Key with highest occurrence"?, I guess you are trying to find out the "value" with highest occurrence as you are calling `mapGroup.get(key)`. Correct?

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar  yes, Try to find out the key list with highest occurrence

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can get a single key via

```
Integer max=mapGroup.entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get().getKey();
```

but unfortunately, there is no built-in function for getting all equivalent maximums.

The simplest, straight-forward solution is to find the maximum value first and retrieve all keys mapping to that value afterwards:

```
private List<Integer> testStreamMap(Map<Integer, Long> mapGroup) {
    if(mapGroup.isEmpty())
        return Collections.emptyList();
    long max = mapGroup.values().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
    return mapGroup.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() == max)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Solutions for getting all maximum values of a stream in a single pass, are discussed in “[How to force max() to return ALL maximum values in a Java Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29334404/2711488)”. You will see that single-pass solutions are much more complicated and not worth the effort if your input is an ordinary `Map` (e.g. `HashMap`), which can be iterated multiple times cheaply.

Answer (score 25):

I'm not sure what half your code is trying to do, but to answer your question as per the title, which I'm guessing was meant to be *"find the entry with the highest value"*:

```
Map.Entry<Integer, Long> maxEntry = map.entrySet().stream()
  .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get();
```

Comment: Ha yeah!! I can understand!!

Comment: @Bohemian this will return only single key, How does will return list of keys

Comment: @dumy is it that you want all entries that share the same max value?  If not, what "list" (please give an example).

Comment: @Bohemian let say , Map{key,value}= {1,4},{2,3},{3,4},{4,3} then return list should be 1 and 4 which has highest frequency 4.

Comment: @Dumy did you mean 1 and **3** (which both have 4 in your example)?

Comment: Yes, yes. Sorry I am having a really bad day :(