# Report on a multimap by producing a new map of each key mapped to the count of elements in its collection value

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream, multimap, multi-mapping

Imagine a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) tracking persons, each of whom has a list of assigned tasks.

```java
Map< Person , List< Task > >  personToTasks = 
    Map.of(
        new Person( "Alice" ) , List.of( new Task( "a1" ), new Task( "a2") ) , 
        new Person( "Bob" )   , List.of( new Task( "b1" ) ) , 
        new Person( "Carol" ) , List.of( new Task( "c1" ), new Task( "c2"), new Task( "c3") ) 
    )
;
```

How can I use streams to get a new map, mapping each `Person` to an `Integer` with the count of items found in their list of assigned tasks?

How to get a result equivalent to this hard-coded map:

```java
Map< Person , Integer >  personToTaskCount = 
    Map.of(
        new Person( "Alice" ) , 2 , 
        new Person( "Bob" )   , 1 , 
        new Person( "Carol" ) , 3 
    )
;
```

I have been trying permutations of:

```java
Map < Person, Integer > personToTaskCount = 
        personToTasks.keySet().stream().collect
        (
            Collectors.mapping
            (
                Map.Entry :: getKey ,
                ???
            )
        )
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, here's a possible solution:

```java
Map<Person, Integer> personToTaskCount = personToTasks
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().size()));
```

The [`Map#entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) method returns a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) of the elements in a map, a set of [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) objects. A `Map.Entry` holds the key-value pairing of each entry in the map. We can ask that object for the key and for the value.

In your example case, asking for the value of each `Map.Entry` gets us a `List< Task >`. We can then interrogate that list for its size, the number of elements it contains. This size number is the value we want for your new map, `Map < Person, Integer >`.

Here is an expanded version of the code above, to make more obvious these `Map.Entry` objects in action.

```java
Map < Person, List < Task > > personToTasks =
        Map.of(
                new Person( "Alice" ) , List.of( new Task( "a1" ) , new Task( "a2" ) ) ,
                new Person( "Bob" ) , List.of( new Task( "b1" ) ) ,
                new Person( "Carol" ) , List.of( new Task( "c1" ) , new Task( "c2" ) , new Task( "c3" ) )
        );


Map < Person, Integer > personToTaskCount =
        personToTasks
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                ( Map.Entry < Person, List < Task > > e ) -> { return e.getKey(); } ,
                                ( Map.Entry < Person, List < Task > > e ) -> { return e.getValue().size(); }
                        )
                );
```

Dump results to console.

```java
System.out.println( "personToTasks = " + personToTasks );
System.out.println( "personToTaskCount = " + personToTaskCount );
```

When run.

> personToTasks = {Person[name=Alice]=[Task[title=a1], Task[title=a2]], Person[name=Carol]=[Task[title=c1], Task[title=c2], Task[title=c3]], Person[name=Bob]=[Task[title=b1]]}
>
> personToTaskCount = {Person[name=Bob]=1, Person[name=Alice]=2, Person[name=Carol]=3}