# Java - Displaying key in map with most occurrences - Java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a string and i created a map which schows occurrences of characters:

```
String: "aaa bbbb ccccccccccc ddddd eeee"
map: {a=3, b=4, c=11, d=5, e=4}
```

And i want to display only c, also output:

```
c
```

(because it occurres most of the times).

Comment: What programming language are you using? Is it javascript?

Comment: Do you want to display the key or the value that appears the most? Keys can only appear once in maps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Java8 Stream to find the highest values from map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060294/using-java8-stream-to-find-the-highest-values-from-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the max key using streams like this:

```java
Character maxKey = map.entrySet().stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .get().getKey();
```

Comment: The comparator may be `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.  Here is how I would do it.

Assuming your keys are strings.

- stream the entry set.
- get the max using the Entry comparator for value.
- get the Entry of the optional and then get the string.

```
Map<String, Integer> maps = Map.of("c", 11, "d", 17, "f", 12);
String key = maps.entrySet().stream()
        .max(Entry.comparingByValue())
        .get().getKey();
System.out.println(key);
```

prints

```
d
```

You can also combine the two operations and use the `chars().stream()` method.

- stream the characters
- map to a Character object.
- and count the characters grouping by the character
- stream the entry set as before
- and return the character.

```
String str = "aaa bbbb ccccccccccc ddddd eeee";
char key = str.chars()
        .mapToObj(ch -> Character.valueOf((char) ch))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s,
                Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream().max(Entry.comparingByValue())
        .get().getKey();

System.out.println(key);
```

In this case, prints

```
c
```

If you only want letters to be counted you can filter with `Character.isLetter()`