# Show all the longest words from finite Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have to find all longest words from given file using Streams API. I did it in few steps but looking for some "one liner", actually I processing whole file two times, first to find max length of word and second for comparing all to max length, assuming its not the best for performance ; P Could someone help me? Just look at code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> words = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("alice.txt"));
        OptionalInt longestWordLength = words.stream().mapToInt(String::length).max();
        Map<Integer, List<String>> groupedByLength = words.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));
        List<String> result = groupedByLength.get(longestWordLength.getAsInt());
    }
}
```

I wish to make it straight:

```
List<String> words = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("alice.txt"));
List<String> result = // code
```

File contains just one word per line, anyway it's not important - question is about the right stream code.

Comment: Does it have to be with streams?

Comment: Iterating two times is not always the worst thing to do. What’s more offending is this entirely unnecessary `groupingBy`, just to get the one group afterward, instead of a straight-forward `int longest = longestWordLength.getAsInt(); List<String> result = list.stream() .filter(s -> s.length() == longest) .collect(toList());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of just keeping the largest length, you could collect the words into a map from their length to the words, and then just take the longest one:

```
List<String> longestWords =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("alice.txt"))
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length))
         .entrySet()
         .stream()
         .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, List<String>> comparingByKey().reversed())
         .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
         .findFirst()
         .orElse(null);
```

**EDIT:**

As Malte Hartwig noted, using `max` on the streamed map is much more elegant (and probably faster):

```
List<String> longestWords =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("alice.txt"))
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length))
         .entrySet()
         .stream()
         .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
         .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
         .orElse(null);
```

**EDIT2:**

There's a built-in inefficiency in both the above solutions, as they both build a map a essentially store the lengths for **all** the strings in the file instead of just the longest ones. If performance is more important than elegance in your usecase, you could write your own `Collector` to just preserve the longest strings in list:

```
private static int stringInListLength(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream().map(String::length).findFirst().orElse(0);
}

List<String> longestWords =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("alice.txt"))
         .collect(Collector.of(
             LinkedList::new,
             (List<String> list, String string) -> {
                 int stringLen = string.length();
                 int listStringLen = stringInListLength(list);
                 if (stringLen > listStringLen) {
                     list.clear();
                 }
                 if (stringLen >= listStringLen) {
                     list.add(string);
                 }
             },
             (list1, list2) -> {
                 int list1StringLen = stringInListLength(list1);
                 int list2StringLen = stringInListLength(list2);
                 if (list1StringLen > list2StringLen) {
                     return list1;
                 }
                 if (list2StringLen > list1StringLen) {
                     return list2;
                 }
                 list1.addAll(list2);
                 return list1;
             }
         ));
```

Comment: maan you're amazing, i was so close with my own solution. thanks!

Comment: By adding the `sorted` operation you're introducing a bit of overhead (`nlogn` operations for sorting at best) that can be reduced to `n` operations with a `reduce`

Comment: @minizibi You can max it a bit easier to read (imo) by using `Stream.max(Comparator)` instead of `sorted().findFirst()`: `...entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).map(Map.Entry::getValue).orElse(null)`. This saves a line, is more straightforward (no reversed call e.g.) and faster (I imagine max to be faster than sort, as it doesn't need as many comparisons).

Comment: @MalteHartwig d`oh! Don't know what I was thinking there. Thanks!

Comment: That `stringInListLength` could be implemented as `list.isEmpty()? 0: list.get(0).length()`… Further, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339106/2711488) might be a good read.

Answer (score 3):

[`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) will help you:

```
    Optional<String> longest = words.stream()
            .reduce((s1, s2) -> {
                if (s1.length() > s2.length())
                    return s1;
                else
                    return s2;
            });
```

In case the `Stream` is empty it will return an `Optional.empty`

In case you want the list of all the words that have the maximum length this piece will help you:

```
    Optional<List<String>> longest = words.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    String::length,
                    Collectors.toList()
            ))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .reduce(
                    (entry1, entry2) -> {
                        if (entry1.getKey() > entry2.getKey())
                            return entry1;
                        else
                            return entry2;
                    }
            )
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate over the map keys to find the longest wordlength

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String s = "hello himanshu i am in Pune";
    
String longest = Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).orElse(null).toString();

System.out.println(longest+" and the length- "+longest.length());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The original question asks for the longest words from a file. Your solution uses only a single string. Also, if the string contains more than one longest word, i.e. two words have the same length and the length of each is the longest, your solution will return only one of them.