# Using Java streams to find mode when there might be multiple modes?

Tags: java, java-stream

examples i have seen for finding mode using stream api return a single mode and if there are two elements that occur equally, the first is returned. however, returning an array with both (or more than 2) elements i can find no example of. i am not sure if there is a simple tweak of the following code:

```
Integer mode = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, () -> new TreeMap<Integer, Long>(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream().sorted((a, b) -> {
                if (!a.getValue().equals(b.getValue()))
                    return b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue());
                return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());
            }).findFirst().get().getKey();
```

Instead of Integer mode I am trying to get `Integer[] mode` or `List<Integer> mode`.

Comment: Can you share an input output example please?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to invert the frequency `Map`, and get the last entry of the inverted `Map`:

```
List<Integer> modes = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                                       Collectors.counting())) // Map<Integer,Long>
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, // TreeMap<Long,List<Integer>>
                                       TreeMap::new,
                                       Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                          Collectors.toList())))
        .lastEntry()
        .getValue(); // you want the last value of the TreeMap
```

Sample Input:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,3,2,4,5,6);
```

Output List:

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

Notes:

1. The first `Map` doesn't have to be a `TreeMap`, since you don't care about the order of its keys.
2. By making the second `Map` a `TreeMap`, the ordering is taken care of, and you don't need to use `sorted()`.

Comment: Isn't `return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey())` in the question, a hint to care about the ordering?

Comment: @Naman perhaps, and perhaps not. We'll see what the OP thinks about this.

Comment: A second grouping operation looks like overkill to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special variant of the question [How to force max() to return ALL maximum values in a Java Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29334404/2711488)

The simplest solution is to identify the maximum value first and filter all elements, keeping those matching the maximum value:

```
Map<Integer, Long> frequencies = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()));

long maxCount = frequencies.values().stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).max().orElse(0);

List<Integer> all = frequencies.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() == maxCount)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively, you can use the collector of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30497254/2711488) to get all maximum elements in a single stream operation, which allows to chain it to the first operation, as you don’t need to access the frequency map twice:

```
List<Integer> all = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(maxAll(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(),
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

But this is only simpler if you don’t count the collector implementation, i.e. if you add it permanently to your code base because you need it more often.