# Grouping by to find a minimum stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following (simplifying my real classes) `HashMap<User, Counter>` and

```
class User {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
}

class Counter {
  private Integer numberOfQuestions;
  private Long maxQuestionId;
}
```

I would like to find the sum of number of questions for the minimum age.

Ex.

```
UserA, 20 -> 11, 100L;
UserB, 25 -> 15, 100L;
UserC, 23 -> 30, 100L;
UserD, 20 -> 11, 100L,
UserE, 25 -> 15, 100L;
```

The result should be 22 -> sum of the minimum number of question per age (age: 20, nOfQuestions 11+11=22)

I tried with java streams:

```
    Integer min = userQuestionHashMap.entrySet().stream()
// not working    .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey::getAge), 
                      summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue::getNumOfQuestion))
                   )
// missing
                    .mapToInt(value -> value.getValue().getNumOfQuestion())
                    .min().orElse(0);
```

Comment: Why 22 and not 11?

Comment: @ernest_k I would like to group by age, so for the age of 20 we have 2 users (UserA and User D): 11 + 11 = 22

Comment: Then you probably need to rephrase that to something like: the sum of number of questions for the minimum age

Comment: You're right, reading again it makes definitely sense, Thanks

Comment: How about storing this data in a priority queue adjusted to compare each `User` by his age? (A min-heap could do wonders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group by user age and using `summingInt` as a downstream. Then find min from result map by key:

```
Integer sum = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(entry -> entry.getKey().getAge(),
                    summingInt(value -> value.getValue().getNumberOfQuestions())))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .min(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new)
            .getValue();
```

Comment: In my real case, I've used comparingByValue so in my opinion, this solution is the simplest and flexible

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
static int questionsByYoungest(Map<User, Counter> inputMap) {
    if (inputMap.isEmpty())
        return 0;
    return inputMap.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    e -> e.getKey().getAge(),
                    TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.summingInt(e -> e.getValue().getNumberOfQuestions())
            ))
            .firstEntry().getValue();
}
```

*Test*

```
Map<User, Counter> inputMap = Map.of(
        new User("UserA", 20), new Counter(11, 100L),
        new User("UserB", 25), new Counter(15, 100L),
        new User("UserC", 23), new Counter(30, 100L),
        new User("UserD", 20), new Counter(11, 100L),
        new User("UserE", 25), new Counter(15, 100L));
System.out.println(questionsByYoungest(inputMap)); // prints 22
```

Comment: @ernest_k So few people use the "lookup nearest" methods of `TreeMap` (and `TreeSet`): `first`, `lower` (<), `floor` (<=), `ceiling` (>=), `higher` (>), `last`.

Comment: @ernest_k I was considering your solution as well :)

Comment: @Andreas it seems that for me it's ordering the keys, so the age, and you will get a different value

Comment: Ex. if you use UserA, 40 (instead if UserA, 20) and UserD, 40 (instead of UserD, 20) , you will get a different result

Comment: @NikNik I can undelete if you need to look at it again, I just found that you already have good and simpler solution in these other answers.

Comment: @NikNik If you change both `UserA` and `UserD` from age 20 to age 40, then of course you get a different result, because they are no longer the youngest persons ("minimum age"), `UserC` is at age 23, so the new result is `30`, as it should be.

Comment: @Andreas Ahn I realized that the question is slightly different from what I wanted :D anyways it helped me a lot to find the final solution and yes, it's working for what I asked :). Thanks

Comment: With this solution, you're creating a new `TreeMap` data structure each time you call `questionsByYoungest`, right? With that approach, you're better off just looping through the whole `Map` to find the right key and then loop again (if needed) to do the operation.

Comment: @Spidey you [can do it in single pass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549731/2711488)

Comment: @Holger that's why there's a parenthesis saying `(if needed)`. Most of the time not needed and even if you do it in two loops it won't make the overall complexity a lot worse (and the code readability will be a lot better).

Answer (score 2):

An efficient solution not requiring to build an entire map, is to use the custom collector of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30497254/2711488).

Since it’s written for max elements, we have to either, reverse the comparator:

```
int min = userQuestionHashMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(maxAll(Collections.reverseOrder(
                        Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparingInt(User::getAge))),
                 Collectors.summingInt(e -> e.getValue().getNumberOfQuestions())));
```

or create a specialized min version

```
public static <T, A, D> Collector<T, ?, D> minAll(
    Comparator<? super T> comparator, Collector<? super T, A, D> downstream) {
    Supplier<A> downSupplier = downstream.supplier();
    BiConsumer<A, ? super T> downAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
    BinaryOperator<A> downCombiner = downstream.combiner();
    Function<A, D> downFinisher = downstream.finisher();
    class Container {
        A acc;
        T obj;
        boolean hasAny;

        Container(A acc) {
            this.acc = acc;
        }
    }
    return Collector.of(() -> new Container(downSupplier.get()),
        (c, t) -> {
            int cmp = c.hasAny? comparator.compare(t, c.obj): -1;
            if (cmp > 0) return;
            if(cmp != 0) {
                c.acc = downSupplier.get();
                c.obj = t;
                c.hasAny = true;
            }
            downAccumulator.accept(c.acc, t);
        },
        (c1, c2) -> {
            if(!c1.hasAny) return c2;
            int cmp = c2.hasAny? comparator.compare(c1.obj, c2.obj): -1;
            if(cmp > 0) return c2;
            if(cmp == 0) c1.acc = downCombiner.apply(c1.acc, c2.acc);
            return c1;
        },
        c -> downFinisher.apply(c.acc));
}
```

Then, you can use it like

```
int min = userQuestionHashMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(minAll(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparingInt(User::getAge)),
        Collectors.summingInt(e -> e.getValue().getNumberOfQuestions())));
```

or alternatively

```
int min = userQuestionHashMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(minAll(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getKey().getAge()),
        Collectors.summingInt(e -> e.getValue().getNumberOfQuestions())));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the fastest way:

```
    int minAge = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int total = 0;

    for (Map.Entry me : map.entrySet()) {
      if (me.getKey().age < minAge) {
        minAge = me.getKey().age;
        total = me.getValue().numberOfQuestions;
      } else if (me.getKey().age.equals(minAge)) {
        total += me.getValue().numberOfQuestions;
      }
    }
```

You only go once through the map.

Comment: I would highly recommend not using `forEach()` here and use a normal `for` loop, so you don't have to do that bad array stuff to circumvent the effectively-final requirement of lambda expressions.

Comment: Totally agree, will change it. Also saves cost of streaming.

Comment: You get even more efficient when you declare `minAge` and `total` as `int`. It eliminates unboxing and reboxing for `<` and `+=` and also allows replacing `me.getKey().age.equals(minAge)` with `me.getKey().age == minAge`.