# How to get all elements with the highest value with Java streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following pojo:

```
class MyPojo {
    String name;
    int priority;
}
```

I have a `List<MyPojo>`. Now, I want to retrieve all elements which have the highest priority. The order of those elements does not matter.

Is this possible with Java streams? I think I should first group by priority and then get all elements belonging to the highest priority, but I am not sure how to do this in an efficient manner.

Comment: You can write a custom collector called `maxList` as @Stuart Marks suggests here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334404/how-to-force-max-to-return-all-maximum-values-in-a-java-stream

Comment: Intestsing stuff, the ad-hoc collector is what I *really* wanted, as this is what I had in mind when thinking procedurally.

Comment: It's more elegant solution, and it promotes reuse too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a `TreeMap` and the `Collectors.groupingBy()`:

```java
TreeMap<Integer, List<MyPojo>> map = pojos.stream()
                                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                              MyPojo::getPriority, 
                                              TreeMap::new, 
                                              Collectors.toList()
                                           ));

List<MyPojo> maxPrios = map.lastEntry().getValue();
```

The `lastEntry()` will return the pojos with the highest priority, due to the natural ordering of `Integer`s where the smallest value will be first, and the largest value will be last.

Answer (score 5):

You should cast it to `IntStream` and get the `max()` out of it.
And then get every pojos with this value.

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class MyPojo {
    String name;
    int priority;

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyPojo> list = null;
        int max = list.stream().mapToInt(MyPojo::getPriority).max().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        List<MyPojo> maxPojos = list.stream().filter(pojo -> pojo.getPriority() == max).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This loops twice through the list. Is there a way to solve this with Java streams by first grouping and then getting the first (highest) group? This should be more efficient, I believe.

Comment: Look at @Lino's answer.