# How to get the max by key of the result of groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an arraylist, `aliens`, of the following objects:

```
  public class Alien{
    public int[] pos;
    public int speed;
    
    public Alien(int[] pos, int speed) {
      this.pos = pos;
      this.speed = speed;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "(" + this.speed + ")[" + this.pos[0] + "," + this.pos[1] + "]";
    }
  }
```

and I've gotten this far with what I'm looking for, assuming I'm going in the right direction:

```
aliens.stream()
      .filter(x -> x.pos[1] == SpaceInvaders.ship)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.pos[0]));
```

where `SpaceInvaders.ship` is an int representing the column that I'm looking to intersect on. If you print this out, it shows `{0=[(2)[0,4], (-3)[0,4]], 1=[(-7)[1,4]]}`, indicating that they are correctly grouped by the first element of their position. As you can see, the positions aren't necessarily unique, so I need to do some processing on a group to determine other criterion, but I need to only process the group with the highest value key. If I use `maxBy` the way that most of the online documentation describes, I get the max for each group, but I need only the max **of the groups** by the key representing the row the alien is on.

I'm stuck at this point. How does one do a `maxBy` on the keys of the return value of a `collect(groupingBy())`?

Comment: There’s no need for grouping at all. `OptionalInt max = aliens.stream() .filter(x -> x.pos[1] == SpaceInvaders.ship) .mapToInt(x -> x.pos[0]) .max(); if(max.isPresent()) { int maxKey = max.getAsInt(); List<Alien> matches = aliens.stream() .filter(x -> x.pos[1] == SpaceInvaders.ship && x.pos[0] == maxKey) .collect(Collectors.toList()); }` See also [How to force max to return ALL maximum values in a Java Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339106/2711488). It’s iterating twice, but in most cases still more efficient than grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to get a map entry by max key:

1. Use sorted map like `TreeMap` and then get use `lastEntry` method:

```java
TreeMap<Integer, List<Alien>> map =  aliens.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.pos[1] == SpaceInvaders.ship)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            x -> x.pos[0], TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()
        ));
System.out.println(map.lastEntry());
```

2. (by Holger's comment) Use [`Stream::max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) returning `Optional` result

```java
aliens.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.pos[1] == SpaceInvaders.ship)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.pos[0])) // non-sorted map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()) // returns Optional<Map.Entry>
        .ifPresent(System.out::println); // print entry with max key if available
```

3. Sort entries of the `aliens` by key in reverse order and pick up only one entry:

```java
aliens.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.pos[1] == SpaceInvaders.ship)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.pos[0])) // non-sorted map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, List<Alien>>comparingByKey().reversed())
        .limit(1)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This is the information I was missing for sure. I was having trouble figuring out the type of the return, and when I found it was a map, I was able to move forward from there. The `entrySet()` to get it back into a stream, and then `comparingByKey()` are much cleaner than what I arrived at independently. Love it!

Comment: `sorted(comparator.reversed()).limit(1)`? Why not `max(comparator)`?

Comment: @Holger, you're right, this option just fell through the cracks