# Java - Get most common elements in arrayList of Object

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` that looks like this:

```
ArrayList<TravelData> listOfTravels;
```

and `TravelData` object contains the following elements

```
int id;
String groupName;
String guideName;
```

This is how I initialize the arrayList:

```
listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(1,"group a", "Ross"));
listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(2,"group a", "Chandler"));
listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(3,"group a", "Monica"));
listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(4,"group b", "Phoebe"));
listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(5,"group b", "Rachel"));
listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(6,"group c", "Joey"));
listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(7,"group c", "Rachel"));
listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(8,"group d", "Chandler"));
```

I want to get the top 3 most common groups and guides on that list.
In this example:

```
Top 3 groups: "group a", "group b", "group c"
Top 3 guides: "Rachel", "Chandler", "Ross"
```

(The third place of guides could be anyone else because Ross, Monica, Phoebe and Joey have the same appearance count).

I found good answers like [how to get the most common element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031213/java-get-most-common-element-in-a-list) but it's only good for `ArrayList` of integers and shows only the first most common element.

Comment: In the linked Q&A, look into `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TravelDate::getGroupName, Collectors.counting()))` and then order by values to get the corresponding values. Similarily for `TravelDate::getGuideName`.

Comment: What is your solution. What did you try so far? Please update question with your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will help you.

```
public class TravelData {
int id;
String groupName;
public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public String getGuideName() {
    return guideName;
}

String guideName;

public TravelData(int id, String groupName, String guideName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.groupName = groupName;
    this.guideName = guideName;
}

public static void getcommonGroups(ArrayList<TravelData>  list){
    Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for(TravelData td:list){
        if(wordMap.containsKey(td.getGroupName())){
            wordMap.put(td.getGroupName(), wordMap.get(td.getGroupName())+1);
        } else {
            wordMap.put(td.getGroupName(), 1);
        }
    }

    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortedList = sortByValue(wordMap);
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:sortedList){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" ===="+entry.getValue());
    } }

  public static List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortByValue(Map<String, Integer> 
  wordMap)  {

    Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> set = wordMap.entrySet();
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(set);
    Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
    {
        public int compare( Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2 )
        {
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );
        }
    } );
    return list;
}


public static  void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<TravelData> listOfTravels=new ArrayList() ;
    listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(1,"group a", "Ross"));
    listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(2,"group a", "Chandler"));
    listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(3,"group a", "Monica"));
    listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(4,"group b", "Phoebe"));
    listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(5,"group b", "Rachel"));
    listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(6,"group c", "Joey"));
    listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(7,"group c", "Rachel"));
    listOfTravels.add(new TravelData(8,"group d", "Chandler"));
    getcommonGroups(listOfTravels);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `hashMap` structure for `groups` where the `key` will be `groupName`  and the value will be the number of occurences.

Then, just `sort` the `hashMap` structure by value `descending` and get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution with Streams.

```java
// comparator for reverse sorting
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Long>> reversed = Map.Entry.comparingByValue();
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Long>> entryComparator = Collections.reverseOrder(reversed);

List<String> collect = listOfTravels.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TravelData::getGuideName, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(entryComparator)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .limit(3)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(collect);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for streams. The idea is, to first transform the `List<TravelData>` to `Map<String, Integer>` of group to number of guides (or guide to number of groups) and then sort that map by the numbers, take only the map's keys (groups/guide) and limit it to the first three elements.

I am assuming that TravelData has the methods `String getGroup()` and `String getGuide()`:

> Using Java 11 type inference in the example

```
final comparator = Comparator.comparing(Map::getValue)
                             .reversed();

final top3Groups = listOfTravels.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TravelData::getGroup(),
                                                                        Collectors.counting())
                                .entrySet()
                                .stream().sorted(comparator)
                                         .map(Map::getKey)
                                         .limit(3)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());

final top3Guides = listOfTravels.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TravelData::getGuide(),
                                                                        Collectors.counting())
                                .entrySet()
                                .stream().sorted(comparator)
                                         .map(Map::getKey)
                                         .limit(3)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```